# How can I get out of this teleporting loop in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I was trying to prank a friend, and accidentally created the loop on myself, and now I'm stuck. I don't know where the command block is, and it's on MC Realms. I used the command /tp @a -0 -0 -0. The Realm World is a flatworld, so I'm suspended over the void. Please help!!! I'm stuck, and I have an infinite timer going on somewhere.

Comment: More details please. The command you used would be a good start